# focus on dynamically generated div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am generating div in the controller dynamically .there can be n number of div's.I am doing this by ajax and in the response i am generating div.and now on keydown i want to focus on this div.i manage to do keydown effect.I tried focus but its not working.
Here is my div generated dynamically in the controller

```
echo '<div class="col-md-12 srch-result" style="cursor:pointer;text-indent:10px;padding:5px 0px 5px 3px" data-uid="'.$rows->user_id.'" data-uname="'.$rows->firstname." ".$rows->lastname.'">'.str_ireplace($keyword,'<b>'.$keyword.'</b>',$rows->firstname." ".$rows->lastname).'</div>'
```

and my code in the view to append this result inside a div

```
$('#page_to').keyup(function(){

            var keyword = $('#page_to').val();

            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'<?php echo base_url("user/userlist"); ?>',
                data:'keyword='+keyword,
                success:function(response)
                {
                    $('#search-result').show();
                    $('#search-result').show('1000');
                    $('#search-result').html(response);
                }


            });

        });
```

Comment: What do you mean by focus on `div`?

Comment: If you want to capture keyboard events on a `div` you need to set the `tabindex` attribute on it. You will also need to use a delegated event handler in this case as the element is appended to the DOM dynamically

Comment: it is like search module like facebook search for friends and by kedown you can go down

Comment: Please show your code where you focus the div